# How to return a LINQ query properly in a function?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I am using LINQ/C# and trying to return the query's result from a function. What I have is below and does not work. Any suggestions? I know this should go into my Model but one step at a time. When I can get this to work I will then move to model.

Currently my Listbox in the button1_Click is only returning the table names. Example Table1.Table2.

```
        public IQueryable runDBQuery()
        {

            Variables obj = new Variables();
            var urlList = from SURL in db.SteamURLs
                          where obj.UserID == SURL.uID
                          select SURL;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = urlList;

            return urlList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var urlList = runDBQuery();

            // This doesn't work?
            listBox1.DataSource = urlList;
        }
```

ANSWER:

```
public IList<SteamURL> runDBQuery()
        {

            Variables obj = new Variables();
            var query = from SURL in db.SteamURLs
                          where obj.UserID == SURL.uID
                          select SURL;

            var urlList = query.ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = urlList;

            urlList.ToList();

            return urlList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var urlList = runDBQuery();

            // This doesn't work?
            listBox1.DataSource = urlList;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "itemURL";

        }
```

Comment: "Does not work". Why not? Also.. an `IQueryable` is deferred.. you really should be returning `IList`/`IEnumerable` and calling `.ToList()` on the query.

Comment: When I try to put it into my listBox it does not work. The listbox just gives me the string of the tables.
SteamFetch.SteamURL.....I edited the above

Comment: What do you mean it gives you "the string of the tables"?  The table name?  You *are* `select`'ing the entire entity `StreamURL` -- not one of the columns.  Are you sure that's what you are trying to do?  And not `select SURL.YourColumn`?

Comment: I know that when I do dataGridView1.DataSource = urlList. My datagrid is populated appropriately. When I do listbox1.Datasource = urlList in the other function it does not work. Can you explain why the above does not work I might understand a bit better then.

Comment: @allencoded, yes, because a grid is designed to display tabular data -- so each column (property) of your entity is displayed in the grid.  Lists are designed to display ordinary data -- one row per item in your datasource.  Given that -- what exactly is the list supposed to display when you've given it no indication of what column you want to show?  (P.S. you *could* override `.ToString` of your entity, and display that column, but that's probably not the best approach.

Comment: Thanks so much Kirk that explains a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to tell the ListBox to be databound to an entire set of fields represented by the `SteamURL` entity, but the Listbox (which has only a single column that it can *display*) has no idea which one of the fields to display so it's just showing a default string to represent "an object is bound to this entry in the list".

you need to tell the ListBox what the `DisplayMember` property is.

e.g if there is a property on a `SteamURL` called `URL` (just guessing) then before this line

```
listBox1.DataSource = urlList;
```

put this:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember="URL";
```

and it should work. I second all the recommendations above by the way, do not return or bind to an IQueryable in this case - you should transform urlList using ToList() or similar first:

```
var query= from SURL in db.SteamURLs
                         where obj.UserID == SURL.uID
                         select SURL;
//this "materialises" the query and fetches the results back from the database. 
        var urlList= query.ToList(); 
//This means that you won't inadvertently trigger another database access by referring to urlList later on.
       dataGridView1.DataSource = urlList;
       return urlList;
```